# List of GNU Emacs enhancement requests, bugs, and milestones at any given time

Tags: emacs-development

In GitHub one can often find, for a given open-source project, the list of issues that have been reported and the estimated time-horizon that is considered for a given fix or enhancement.

Is there an equivalent repository where feature requests and bugs for GNU Emacs are collected and prioritized? Do the developers group them into specific milestones per version?

Comment: For the record, there's another good answer on [this duplicate](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/how-do-i-make-a-bug-report-or-feature-request-against-gnu-emacs).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One place where emacs bugs are filed/listed is [debbugs](http://debbugs.gnu.org/db/pa/lemacs.html).  Other places to discover/place feature requests and follow development include the emacs and emacs-devel [discussion lists](https://savannah.gnu.org/mail/?group_id=40).

Answer (score 3):

You can browse the requests correctly filed in [debbugs](http://debbugs.gnu.org/db/pa/lemacs.html) from Emacs: just install the `debbugs` package (e.g. using `M-x package-install`), and then:

`M-x debbugs-gnu`

Answer (score 1):

As @JordonBiondo reported [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2110/6) (this answer is a verbatim copy of his answer):

The procedure for reporting bugs, requesting features, and submitting pathces is outlined in the manual.

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Bugs</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

Or read online:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html

In a nutshell:

- use `report-emacs-bug` for bug reporting and feature requests
- ask the dev mailing list if you think your request requires more discussion
- check the existing bugs and search the mailing list to see if the topic has already been discussed and concluded upon
- read the manual for how to send patches
- subscribe to emacs-devel or even bug-gnu-emacs if you want to be more involved or informed about what is happening in emacs development.

Also read [etc/CONTRIBUTE](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/CONTRIBUTE) and [BUGS](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/BUGS)

Comment: Stack exchange is about sharing knowledge and all, but I'd say it's good manners to leave the other answer a comment before you verbatim copy it. =)

Comment: Thanks @Marbara I think you are right, I was hesitant to do it at first, and your comment confirms my doubts. I also thought I could do it CW, but I think it's best to delete the answer, and let him respond (if he wants) :)

Comment: in situations like this, it's better to copy an answer than to not have it here. But it's always nice to give them the chance to copy it here first.

Comment: A comment would be nice, but as long as the information is out there I don't really care who get's the attribution or magical internet points. Community Wiki'ing it was a good call, I was going to do that with my other post.

Comment: Thanks @JordonBiondo I CWed it, but please feel free to add it as an answer and I will delete this one.