# How do I make a bug report or feature request against GNU Emacs?

Tags: debugging

I found this list at the emacswiki:

```
FFI (foreign function interface). Would be great to have this in GNU.
Enhanced Numerics. We sorely need this too.
Apparently much better multimedia support (Of particular interest to me.)
Doubly-linked lists, skip lists, and some other possibly interesting data structures.
```

Does Emacs have a feature request location, or even somewhere to post issues?

Comment: Bugs and feature requests can be reported with `M-x report-emacs-bug`, and viewed at http://debbugs.gnu.org/.

Comment: // , As to the duplicate mark, the answer to this question may be a duplicate of the answer to that, but I doubt that a naive user would think to search for "List of GNU Emacs enhancement requests, bugs, and milestones at any given time" when they're looking for a way to report a bug. At least, I didn't, and, as it happens, "List..." didn't come up in the emacs.stackexchange.com search results, as follows: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/search?q=How+do+I+make+a+bug+report

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The procedure for reporting bugs, requesting features, and submitting pathces is outlined in the manual.

<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>Bugs</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>

Or read online:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bugs.html

In a nutshell:

- use `report-emacs-bug` for bug reporting and feature requests
- ask the dev mailing list if you think your request requires more discussion
- check the existing bugs and search the mailing list to see if the topic has already been discussed and concluded upon
- read the manual for how to send patches
- subscribe to emacs-devel or even bug-gnu-emacs if you want to be more involved or informed about what is happening in emacs development.

Also read [etc/CONTRIBUTE](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/CONTRIBUTE) and [BUGS](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/BUGS)

Comment: How many people do you think can still send e-mail directly from Linux? Most people have been forced onto webmail platforms.