# Python-mode Multi-line Conditional Indentation

Tags: python, indentation

Given the following somewhat silly Python code with a multi-line condition:

```
if ("VALUE" in my_uncessarily_long_dictionary and
    some_other_long_condition_case):
    do_something()
else:
    pass
```

This is written as Emacs typically indents each line, which I'm normally fine
with. However, quite a few linters prefer the condition to be indented visually
different from the next (non-conditional) line, e.g., something like this:

```
if ("VALUE" in my_uncessarily_long_dictionary and
        some_other_long_condition_case):
    do_something():
else:
    pass
```

Is there some way to configure `python-mode` to indent like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indentation behaviour can now be configured as of commit  `711e8bc7178d5dd78f4db5c34b2b23f605521fc4`, (or Emacs-29 and above I think).

To use it, simply set the `python-indent-block-paren-deeper` option to `t` if you want to enable this indentation behaviour, e.g.:

```
(setq python-indent-block-paren-deeper t)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [following lines within `python-indent--calculate-indentation`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/dec958258b133b4c21224c594da433919d852800/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1163-L1168) determine the indent after a paren not following a newline:

```el
(defun python-indent--calculate-indentation ()
  ...
  (pcase (python-indent-context)
    ...
    (`(,(or :inside-paren
            :after-backslash-block-continuation
            :after-backslash-dotted-continuation) . ,start)
     ;; Use the column given by the context.
     (goto-char start)
     (current-column))
    ...
    )
  )
```

The result of the form `(current-column)` is the calculated indentation. It is hard-coded and changing the indentation after a paren requires changing the code.
You could do that in the following way:

```el
(defcustom phyton-indent-add-after-paren python-indent-offset
  "Additional indent after paren."
  :type 'number
  :group 'python)

(defun python-indent--calculate-indentation ()
  ...
  (pcase (python-indent-context)
    ...
    (`(:inside-paren . ,start)
     (goto-char start)
     (+ (current-column) phyton-indent-add-after-paren))
    (`(,(or :after-backslash-block-continuation
            :after-backslash-dotted-continuation) . ,start)
     ;; Use the column given by the context.
     (goto-char start)
     (current-column))
    ...
    )
  )
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the following advice in your init file:

```el
(defcustom phyton-indent-add-after-paren python-indent-offset
  "Additional indent after paren without following newline."
  :type 'number
  :group 'python)

(defun python-indent-calc-indent-ad (fun)
  "Change indent after opening paren with `phyton-indent-add-after-paren'.
This is an around advice for `python-indent--calculate-indentation'."
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((info (python-indent-context))
       (ctx (car info))
       (start (cdr info)))
      (if (eq ctx :inside-paren)
      (progn
        (goto-char start)
        (+ (current-column) python-indent-offset))
    (funcall fun)))))

(advice-add 'python-indent--calculate-indentation :around #'python-indent-calc-indent-ad)
```

This is less efficient than the modification of `python-indent--calculate-indentation` since the heavy duty function `python-indent-context` is called twice. But if you do not notice the slow down, it should be okay.

---

Note, this is valid for Emacs 28.1.
It may be that other Emacs versions require other changes.

You could issue a feature request at [debbugs](https://debbugs.gnu.org/emacs). See [an SE-answer about feature requests](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2110/2370).

Comment: I applied this (almost) as is to Emacs (master) and it seems to work fine. I did notice an inconsistency that anything within parentheses can be "extra" indented, but that should be solvable with a quick backward search for `if` or `elif`

Comment: I'll package this up as a patch for Emacs when I have a bit more time

Comment: This has now been reported/packaged in the following bug-ticket: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62696, feel free to follow along

Comment: @Xaldew Thanks for submitting the patch. (Even if I don't use Python.)